# npm semver version invalid issue with grunt installation

Tags: gruntjs, npm, semantic-versioning

While installing grunt, one of the errors is `unmet dependency semver@4`

i am using `node@0.10.33`, `npm@1.4.28`

i run two commands and it shows two versions and one is invalid

```
npm list -g
```

and in the tree it shows `semver@2.3.0 invalid`

now i run

```
npm view semver version
```

now it shows `4.1.0`

i tried npm update semver 
but nothing happens

i have even tried to the solution provided in similar question [npm error invalid semver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19422949/npm-error-invalid-semver)

```
curl https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

but donesnt help

I am new to npm and grunt please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what do you mean by `While installing grunt`? 
Installing the grunt-cli tools or the grunt-runner in your project?

since 4.0 grunt is split into 2 modules:

- [grunt-cli](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-cli)
- [grunt](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt)

[grunt-cli](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-cli) needs to be installed globally, and only 1 time:

```
$ npm install grunt-cli -g
```

[grunt](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt) needs to be installed locally in every project where you want to use grunt and grunt-plugins:

```
$ npm install grunt
```

---

**updating npm:**

the crazy stuff about npm is, that you can even update npm via npm:

```
$ npm update npm -g
```

the current npm version is 2.1.9, so maybe this solves your problem.

hint: use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) vor node.js version management. this solves multiple problems:

1. easy version switching
2. you don't need sudo for global packages